# Matrix multiplication of two vectors

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to do a matrix multiplication of two vectors in numpy which would result in an array.

**Example**

```
In [108]: b = array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
In [109]: a =array([1,2,3])
In [111]: b.shape
Out[111]: (4, 1)
In [112]: a.shape
Out[112]: (3,)
In [113]: b.dot(a)
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

As can be seen from the shapes, the array a isn't actually a matrix. The catch is to define `a` like this.

```
In [114]: a =array([[1,2,3]])    
In [115]: a.shape
Out[115]: (1, 3)    
In [116]: b.dot(a)
Out[116]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 3,  6,  9],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

---

How to achieve the same result when acquiring the vectors as fields or columns of a matrix?

```
In [137]: mat = array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 3,  6,  9],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])

In [138]: x = mat[:,0]      #[1,2,3,4]
In [139]: y = mat[0,:]      #[1,2,3]
In [140]: x.dot(y)
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are computing the [outer product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two vectors.  You can use the function [`numpy.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) for this:

```
In [18]: a 
Out[18]: array([1, 2, 3])

In [19]: b
Out[19]: array([10, 20, 30, 40])

In [20]: numpy.outer(b, a)
Out[20]: 
array([[ 10,  20,  30],
       [ 20,  40,  60],
       [ 30,  60,  90],
       [ 40,  80, 120]])
```

Comment: This is an archetypal StackExchange answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use 2d arrays instead of 1d vectors and broadcasting with the `*` ...

```
In [8]: #your code from above

In [9]: y = mat[0:1,:]

In [10]: y
Out[10]: array([[1, 2, 3]])

In [11]: x = mat[:,0:1]

In [12]: x
Out[12]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])

In [13]: x*y
Out[13]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 3,  6,  9],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

Comment: `x.dot(y)` and `x * y` both work in this case, the trick is to use slices so that both `x` and `y` are 2d arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It's the similar catch as in the basic example.

Both `x` and `y` aren't perceived as matrices but as single dimensional arrays.

```
In [143]: x.shape
Out[143]: (4,)

In [144]: y.shape
Out[144]: (3,)
```

We have to add the second dimension to them, which will be 1.

```
In [171]: x = array([x]).transpose()
In [172]: x.shape
Out[172]: (4, 1)
In [173]: y = array([y])
In [174]: y.shape
Out[174]: (1, 3)
In [175]: x.dot(y)
Out[175]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 3,  6,  9],
       [ 4,  8, 12]])
```

Comment: Instead of `x = array([x]).transpose()`, you can just do `x.reshape(-1,1)` or `x[...,np.newaxis]`, neither of which creates a new array.